# Using variables to refer to dataframe colums

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R programming. I'm stuck with the following problem:

I have an array of column names and need to use them sequentially inside a for loop.
The problem I have is that I find no way to refer to these columns using variable names:

```
df <- MyFrame
colNames <- names(df)
for(i in colNames) `enter code here`{
   tempDF <- subset(df, <condition>, select c(date, week, colNames[i]), drop = FALSE)
}
```

date and week are actual column names of df. If I type the third column name, it works, but if I use colNames[i], I get an error message.
I looked everywhere but found no answer to this issue.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `tempDF <- df[, c("date", "week", i), drop = FALSE]`. `i` already is the name of the i-th column.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan.  It works perfectly!  The <condition> I was making reference to when using subset was to ignore (not include) empty rows.   Now I have some tempDF rows with NA values.  What would you suggest to get rid of those rows?

Comment: Stefan, I found a way around it.  After passing the values to tempDF, I changed the name of the columns (variables) to standard names (i.e. "Value" and "Origin").  I then could use: tempDF<-subset(tempDF, !is.na(Value), select=c(date, week, volume, origin)).  That made the trick.  Thank you again!